# How to detect and read facebook Emojis in Microsoft BOT framework

Tags: botframework, facebook-chatbot

I want to create an interaction based on the Emojis passed from facebook user on chatbot. Not able to get anything related to parsing the value at BOT end. Chatbot solution with normal text is working fine.

Comment: Did you log what you received in the message? can you add that here?

Comment: For clarification, when you say 'based on emojis', do you mean if the user sends a frowny face, the chat bot will respond with "I'm sorry you're sad" (or similar) or respond with another emoji, like an emoji only conversation?